# Error when running ./manage.py Validate

Tags: django, manage.py

When I run the command

```
  ./manage.py validate
```

I get the error

```
 Error:No module named debugger.debugger
```

I have debugger installed in my virtual environment via pip.

Comment: There is no stack trace.There is only one line of error

Comment: This error is from your models (that's what validate is checking). So check your models.

Comment: There is no error in my models.If there would have been error in models than there should have been a different error.

Comment: Are you using the [debugger module](https://github.com/horejsek/python-debugger)? It is not a requirement for django, and you said you installed it so I am wondering where are you using it.

Comment: Uninstalling the debugger also results in the same issue. And I don't know if I am using it or not

Comment: If uninstalling it results in the same issue, then you have a file named `debugger.py` somewhere which you are trying to import.

Comment: Can you help? I have two debugger.py  one in lib/python 2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ and two in /local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ ?

Comment: `import debugger` search this str through whole project dir (using your IDE or TexMate or smth else). If this yields no result - try search through your `site-packages` dir

Answer (score 0):

Actually the real problem was because of django-haystack version. Requires was version 2.0.0
So during validate somehow the real error was not showing up. The actual error was an import error during validate.
Thanks everyone for the help